# Everything stops on goto next frame

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I have a huge problem here. I've made about 20 classes and have just buildt up everything that i need in this sidescroller game. Now that i have most of the game features i wanted to start on the leveldesign.

Problem is, when i (on the main timeline) use GotoAndStop(2) the game stops completely. Everything freezes and i can see that it stopped on a mashup of both level1 and level2, because elements from both frames are mixed up together on the screen. And the worst part is, it doesn't give me any errors so i have no idea of what could be the problem. This is my first time working with classes.

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: What code is there in you 2 frame?

Comment: There is no code on the second frame. Everything is in classfiles which have children on both frames

Comment: Although you can, using frames is like rollerblading uphill, on ice, with a bungee attached to your back.  If you're ready to write classes, then you need to learn to change your stage programmatically.  Try saving each "level" in its own container, and show/hide/instantiate them as necessary.